# web crawler HTML and JS "understanding" with python

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-crawler

I am making a web crawler that try to find security issues in web sites (something like w3af). for example finding xss etc...

but I have a problem: my crawler try to find the forms in the pages using regex (I know regex can't pars html but i'm only parsing the *form* tag), anyway I found that some pages (like [google](https://www.google.com)) have the entire page encoded in some sort of ugly JS code and then nothing works, in addition when I inject scripts to the urls and want to check if they execute (reflected xss) I need something that could tell me if (for example) an alert showed up.

so I need a module that will get the source code of a page and will be able to give me the rendered page or if alert occured.

do someone know something that might work? (I'v found some solutions such as selenium but it require a browser and therefor is way to slow...)

thanks ahead!

Comment: you need something to act like a browser. I think selenium is for that

Comment: @Whitefret selenuim is too slow, to process something like 200 on every parameter/form in an ENTIRE website will be impossible!

Comment: you can have a look at that, but the only solution is to have something that act like a browser: https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/